# Speedplay pedal grease problem

Tags: maintenance, pedals, grease

I’m trying to grease my Speedplay pedals, but the little end screw on one of the pedals just spins. It will not unscrew, thereby denying me access to the grease port.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I hope you're using a chainsaw grease gun and didn't pay the outrageous price for a Speedplay-branded grease gun...

Answer (score 3):

What I've done in the past is remove the screw then use a tool to pop off the plastic port. Now I use a Torx head (T25?) to unscrew the retaining screw. The body will then slide off revealing the spindle which I give a good clean with a rag and finish with degreaser. The body can then be cleaned with a series of twisted paper towels to remove the old grease. I finished with light squirt of degreaser and wipe clean.

Once I am ready to reassemble, a good dollop of water-proof marine grade grease into to the body and push back on to the spindle. You will need to wipe the excess that gets pushed out. Then replace the torx screw, nice and tight, the access port and finally the little screw. Finish with a really good rub with a rag to remocve exterior grease and you are good to go.

Don't forget to clean the cleats as well. Depending on how dirty they are, a wipe with a rag to remove dirt etc, maybe a wipe with water. Then let dry. I then use a furniture polish to lubricate.

Comment: My recollection from the X series pedals is that the retaining screw was loctited on, and I believe the instructions were that you had to break the bond with a heat gun or soldering iron. Was this not necessary on your version?

Comment: @WeiwenNg Sometimes. A impact drive will help as well. You just need to clamp the  pedal. By taking apart the pedal you can also replace both sets of bearings if needs be. Having said all that I just 'upgraded' to the new Wahoo version so I won't be able to do anything.

Comment: This seems to be a bit more serious overhaul than OP was looking for, and it's assuming that the grease port screw isn't stripped, so it doesn't really address the original question.

Comment: @DavidW That's fair enough, but I feel it adds to the overall subject matter.

Comment: @DavidW Actually, having had experience on Speedplays, I have a feeling that taking the pedal body off (if able) is better than squirting grease in through the gun. The grease frequently leaks out the wrong side of the pedal if you use the gun before finally getting extruded through the inboard side. I agree that it does apply to the original question. Readers should note that Wahoo Speedplays (offered starting mid 2021) do *not* require this maintenance, as they're completely sealed.

Answer (score 1):

If the screw is just spinning in place, then the thread that it engages in inside the pedal body is worn-out (metal screw and plastic thread aren't a great combo). This means that the screw is no longer apllying pressure to hold the cap into the pedal. Using something small and sharp, you should be able to lever it off to get access to the grease port.